# Too early to create image: no default root window

Tags: python-3.10

I want to display image in windows have yet inserted codes to display image and I am getting an error.
The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vince\PycharmProjects\app5\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    photo1 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\thumbs up.png")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4026, in __init__
    master = _get_default_root('create image')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 297, in _get_default_root
    raise RuntimeError(f"Too early to {what}: no default root window")
RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window
```

and this is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
#from tkinter import messagebox

photo1 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\thumbs up.png")
photo2 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\thumbs down.png")
photo3 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\flower.png")
photo4 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\poop.png")
photo5 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\dry floor.png")
photo6 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\wet floor.png")
photo7 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\no toilet paper.png")
photo8 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\toilet paper.png")
photo9 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\no toilet.png")
photo10 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\toilet.png")
photo11 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\vince\OneDrive\Desktop\ICONS\QR CODE.png")


class Confirmation1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='darkmagenta')

        label1 = Label(self, text='NEXT QUESTION?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=325, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)

class Confirmation2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='darkmagenta')

        label1 = Label(self, text='NEXT QUESTION?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page3))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)

class Confirmation3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='darkmagenta')
        label1 = Label(self, text='NEXT QUESTION?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page4))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page3))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)

class Confirmation4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='darkmagenta')
        label1 = Label(self, text='NEXT QUESTION?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page5))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page4))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='darkmagenta')
        label1 = Label(self, text='HOW WAS YOUR EXPERIENCE ON OUR WASHROOM?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text='Yes' , command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation1))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text='No' , command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation1))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='green')
        label1 = Label(self, text='DOES OUR TOILET SMELL BAD?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150,y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation2))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation2))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)

class Page3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='Tomato')
        label1 = Label(self, text='DOES OUR TOILET HAVE WET FLOOR?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation3))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation3))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)

class Page4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='Tomato')
        label1 = Label(self, text='DOES OUR TOILET HAVE ENOUGH AMENITIES?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation4))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Confirmation4))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)

class Page5(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg='Tomato')
        label1 = Label(self, text='DOES OUR TOILET FLUSH WELL?', font=('Times_New_Roman', 15))
        label1.place(x=150, y=0)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        Button.place(x=100, y=450)
        Button = tk.Button(self, text="No", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        Button.place(x=650, y=450)



class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # creating a window
        window = tk.Frame(self)
        window.pack()
        window.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=500)
        window.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=800)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5, Confirmation1, Confirmation2, Confirmation3, Confirmation4):
            frame = F(window, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Page1)
    def show_frame(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()
        self.title("Application")


app = Application()
app.maxsize(800, 500)
app.mainloop()
```

I did not put .destroy() function in any code yet it is telling me too early to create image, and I do not understand no default root window. I am a newbie in python. Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Too early to create image: no default root window

Meaning. you forgot to add root window.

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#from tkinter import messagebox

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()#<== this prevented garbage window.
...
...
...

app = Application()
app.maxsize(800, 500)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Btw, you need to add images on `Canvas`. I leave that `tk.Canvas` to you. So you can do what you want.

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=600, height=400, bg='white')
canvas.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True)
canvas.create_image((100, 100), image=Photo(?))
```